# Image to np array, doing operations and back to image

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, reverse

Heay guys started with ML and trained my first classifier. 
Used the Microsoft Dataset with dog/cat images.

What im trying is to go Image > array > operations back to an Imagefile. 
I tried so many things and couldnt do it.

I have images(500x500, jpg) that i am reading in with cv2.imread and saving the values in a list. IMG_SIZE = 100

```
img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path, img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
test_data.append([new_array, class_num])


X_test = []
y_test = []

for features, label in test_data:
    X_test.append(features)
    y_test.append(label)

X_test = np.array(X_test).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
X_test = X_test / 255
```

What i tried is just undo the operations.

```
img_orig = X_test[:]
img_orig = img_orig * 255
img_orig.astype(int)
img_orig = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img_orig))
```

getting following error

```
File "xxx\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2460, in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]
  KeyError: ((1, 1, 1), '|u1')

File "xxx\CatDog_predict.py", line 78, in <module>
    img_orig = PIL.Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img_orig))

File "xxx\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2463, in fromarray
    raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type")
  TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

What am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to change this one line of code: `img_orig = img_orig.astype(int)` and then you can probably get rid of the `dtype` conversion using `np.uint8` if you'd just like to view the image.

Answer (score 0):

PIL.Image.fromarray can accommodate a uint8 image on 0-255. To debug, first do this:

```
img_orig = X_test[:]
```

Now you need to verify that `img_orig.max()<=1.0` and `img_orig.min()>=0.0`. You can also verify that the datatype is float with `img_orig.dtype`. Provided these three conditions are true ( you can make them true ), you can do

```
img_orig = img_orig * 255

img_orig = img_orig.astype('uint8')

img_orig = PIL.Image.fromarray(img_orig)
```

You don't need that additional int conversion you have in there.